# Multiple Table Query ORDER BY Then GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Goal: JOIN two tables, ordered by one column (ui.UNO) and then GROUP BY (images.INO).

Problem: ORDER BY returns duplicate results as you would expect but as i am trying to ORDER BY to bring the current users images to the top, if i GROUP BY only the first result is shown no matter if it is linked to another user.

eg: In the table below i am looking for the second result, but if i use GROUP BY only the first result will be displayed and any linked data (ui.IUTally) will be wrong.
Thanks for your help in advance.

```
Images                          
   INO    |    IName    |    IDescription
   3      |    Sports   |    "......"      
   3      |    Sports   |    "......"

UI
   UNO    |    INO     |    IUTally  
   4      |    3       |    12
   7      |    3       |    6
```

.

```
SELECT images.INO, images. IName, ui. UNO, ui. IUTally
FROM images 
LEFT JOIN ui ON images. INO = ui. INO
GROUP BY images. INO
ORDER BY ui. UNO = $uno DESC

Images / UI                           
   INO    |    IName    |    UNO    |    INO     |    IUTally  
   3      |    Sports   |    4      |    3       |    12
   3      |    Sports   |    7      |    3       |    6
```

Comment: I think you're mixing up the `GROUP BY` and the `WHERE` clause. Because you order by 'ui.UNO = $uno', it first checks if it's true or not and then returns 1 or 0.

Comment: What is you expected result ?

Comment: Hi Marty,I am not sure i get what you 100%, if i don't use GROUP BY i get duplicate results, the only reason i am thinking about GROUP BY is because it does what i need, but not in conjunction with ORDER BY, so it seems to be either or, or an alternative. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Shafeeq, the end result would be a list of images, with the users at the top, with their associated data, i.e has the user 'LIKED' the image or not. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the structure of your tables to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the one way to first order your results then group them but this trick includes the sub select , in single query you cannot use `ORDER BY` before the `GROUP BY`  so try this one

```
SELECT q.* FROM (
SELECT images.INO, images. IName, ui. UNO, ui. IUTally
FROM images 
LEFT JOIN ui ON images. INO = ui. INO   
ORDER BY ui. UNO = $uno DESC
) q GROUP BY q. INO
```

it will first order your results and then group them

Comment: Thanks Dianuj, i will try it and report back.

Comment: I have tried your code Dianuj but no luck, the ORDER BY  is overridden  by the GROUP BY, thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Just a note, the result is reordered numerically ascending by the ORDER BY, if that helps?

Comment: @user2784408 can add the sql fiddle with your small data set to it will be helpful for other peoples to understand http://sqlfiddle.com thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to view data linked with other users, you may need to use GROUP_CONCAT function in the SELECT clause like this.

```
SELECT images.INO, GROUP_CONCAT(images.IName ORDER BY ui.UNO), GROUP_CONCAT(ui.UNO ORDER BY ui.UNO), GROUP_CONCAT(ui.IUTally ORDER BY ui.UNO)
FROM images 
LEFT JOIN ui ON images. INO = ui. INO
GROUP BY images. INO
ORDER BY ui. UNO = $uno DESC";
```

Let me know if this helps or you are looking for anything else.